# how to build common api for web and mobile and authenticate with oauth

Tags: node.js, api, rest, mobile, oauth

I'm trying to build common API which I'm planning to consume from various mobile native apps and website. If I were to authenticate users using facebook oauth, how should I design my APIs? What are the best practices and industry standards for providing same content on website and mobile? I'm using node.js and mongodb. I'm able to authenticate users for the website using passport.js but how do I build common web APIs for website and mobile and authenticate users using facebook (or any other oauth providers)?

Spent a lot of time googling but could not find any helpful guide. Please Help!

Answer (score 0):

**Prelude to answer**: I would make it clear what authenticate and authorize mean in the context. Let's deal with the parties here

- The user. First-party
- Intermediate app/vendor. Third-party
- Authentication End-point. Oauth provider. Second-party

Authorize is when Oauth allows third-party to access/use your data (3-2). Authenticate is when user is verified by Auth end-point directly(1-2).

Each Oauth provider(facebook,google,facebook) has its own authorising strategy. So how to deal with it. Have your own database and your API.

1. User logs in (uses facebook)
2. Check for userid, if present authorize/get token, else ask user to register app.
3. On success login.

So how to build common API ? Create your own database and use it as proxy/mirror to user details. Use authorisation like a bridge depending on your requirements.

```
                        /-------Oautha(2)
    User(1) ------ App(3) ------Oauthb(2) 
                        \-------Oauthc(2)
                                depending on registered email       (party)
```